# In Django/python, how do I set the memcache to infinite time?

Tags: python, django, memcached

```
cache.set(key, value, 9999999)
```

But this is not infinite time...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
def _get_memcache_timeout(self, timeout):
    """
    Memcached deals with long (> 30 days) timeouts in a special
    way. Call this function to obtain a safe value for your timeout.
    """
    timeout = timeout or self.default_timeout
    if timeout > 2592000: # 60*60*24*30, 30 days
        # See http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ
        # "You can set expire times up to 30 days in the future. After that
        # memcached interprets it as a date, and will expire the item after
        # said date. This is a simple (but obscure) mechanic."
        #
        # This means that we have to switch to absolute timestamps.
        timeout += int(time.time())
    return timeout
```

And from the [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#What_are_the_limits_on_setting_expire_time?_(why_is_there_a_30_d):

> What are the limits on setting expire time? (why is there a 30 day limit?)
>
> You can set expire times up to 30 days in the future. After that memcached interprets it as a date, and will expire the item after said date. This is a simple (but obscure) mechanic.

Answer (score 11):

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-CACHES-TIMEOUT):

> If the value of this settings is None, cache entries will not expire.

Notably, this is different from how the expiration time works in the Memcache [standard protocol](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/Commands#standard-protocol):

> Expiration times can be set from 0, meaning "never expire", to 30
>   days. Any time higher than 30 days is interpreted as a unix timestamp
>   date

So, to set a key to never expire, set the timeout to `None` if you're using Django's cache abstraction, or `0` if you're using Memcache more directly.

Comment: When I set cache to 0 it doesn't appear to cache at all.

Comment: Setting Timeout to 0 causes keys to immediately expire (effectively “don’t cache” at all). You can set TIMEOUT to None so that, by default, cache keys never expire.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-CACHES-TIMEOUT for details.

Answer (score 8):

Support for non-expiring cache [has been added in Django 1.6](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9595) by setting `timeout=None`

Comment: `Django 1.6.2`, `Memcached 1.4.17`. Was using `timeout=0` and it was same as if i didn't cache at all. `timeout=None` is the way to go for non-expiring cache.

Answer (score -6):

Another simple technique is to write the generated HTML out to a file on the disk, and to use that as your cache. It's not hard to implement, and it works quite well as a file-based cache that NEVER expires, is quite transparent, etc.

It's not the django way, but it works well.

Comment: -1 Question was about memcache, this way it will be much slower.

Comment: Depends. Slower than what? If you are generating a very complicated page, this can be faster than regenerating it from scratch, and yet be fast enough. If you're generating a simple page, this is slower than serving it from memcache.